# Group Constants on FMINCON

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm writing a model that needs to minimize 6 variables by using `fmincon`: `o`, `a`, `b`, `w`, `kappa`, `gamma`. The variable `options` is defined as follows:

```
optimset(optimset(@fmincon),'Diagnostics','off','Display','off','LargeScale','off','MaxSQPIter',1000,'TolFun',1e-6)
```

The variables are already subject to the following lower/upper boundaries:

- `o`, `a`, `b`, `w` between `0` and `Inf`;
- `kappa` and `gamma` strictly positive between `(2 * options.TolCon)` and `Inf`;

I need to ensure a few constraints are respected:

- `o`, `a`, `b`, `w` must approximately sum to `1`;
- `kappa` * `gamma` must be approximately equal to `1`;

If I didn't have to consider the last two variables, I would have probably used `A` and `b` parameters of `fmincon` as follows:

```
A = [-eye(3); ones(1,3)];
b = [(zeros(3,1) + (2 * options.TolCon)); (1 - (2 * options.TolCon))];
```

But going for that approach with two distinct constraints (an additive one and a multiplicative one) is pretty weird and I really have no clue about how to set `A` and `b`.

It seems that the `nonlcon` parameter of `fmincon` may be what I'm looking for, but it's unclear to me how to formulate it properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You won't get around using *inequality constraints* and *nonlinear constraints*.
Lets recall the function-call
[`x_opt = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#d120e73665)
and assuming that you optimization vector looks like this
`x = [o, a, b, w, kappa, gamma]`.

**inequality constraints**: "*`o`, `a`, `b`, `w` must approximately sum to `1`*"... I translated this to be somewhere in a tolerance region of the size `TOL`

```
TOL = 0.01; % your "approximately"
A = [ ones(1,4) 0 0;
     -ones(1,4) 0 0];
b = [ 1+TOL
     -1+TOL];
```

Now the thing that I rarely use:

**nonlinear constraints** [`nonlcon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#busog7r-nonlcon):*`kappa`* * *`gamma` must be approximately equal to `1`*. This is a function handle returning a boolean scalar

```
 nonlcon = @(x) abs(x(5)*x(6)-1) < TOL
```